# Azure Functions keeps loading

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function. It works, I have run it many times.
I want to navigate back to it, but in this frame it just keeps loading with no end to it.

- Its not my internet connection (everything else works)
- Its not Azure in general. The other apps work.
- Its not my computer, my colleagues experience the same this.

Does anyone know what else could be causing this problem?

Does anyone else experience this?

[image]

Comment: I've seen this mentioned mentioned on Twitter several times today. It works fine for my function apps deployed in East US 2

Comment: can you share you functionapp name either here or [indirectly](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately)?

Comment: It works correctly on my side(Azure function deployed in South Central US). If you still have this issue, I recommond that you could create a  [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get more help from Azure team.

Comment: As @HoriaToma mentioned, MS was having some issues earlier in the day. The problem fixed itself after about half an hour. That is MS fixed their problem.